# How to find chess students?

Tags: coach

I was wondering how to find chess students or better said how and where one can advertise himself? I am sure that many chess players are searching for a coach, but they don't know where to find him. Here is my page for example, https://bs.lichess.org/coach/PetarBosnjak, have I mentioned all the needed informations, should I omit something?

Comment: Perhaps you could add by which means you want to teach (skype, on the spot...).

Answer (score 1):

In the UK the busiest chess forum is the [English Chess Forum](http://www.ecforum.org.uk/). They have an [Adverts](http://www.ecforum.org.uk/viewforum.php?f=29&sid=53cdf66ec134b2c78ed2b26c3730877e) topic which would be suitable for you to use.

I should stress that despite the presence of the letters "ecf" in the url it is independent of the English Chess Federation which has its own web site, although senior members of the board do from time to time make announcements and answer questions on the English Chess Forum. This independence allows a much broader range of opinions to be expressed.

Comment: Petar [immediately used the opportunity](http://www.ecforum.org.uk/viewtopic.php?f=29&t=8894&sid=0d4609a0eff87d81556676f5f2788fbf) ;-)